# Can GPUImage make an image local tensile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

I want to make an image local tensile, using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in iOS.

For example:

The next image is the normal image

[image]

After I use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with a right direction on the man's nose, it should look like this:

[image]

If possible, how could I go about doing this using the GPUImage library?

Comment: You're looking for a mesh distortion. I know that others have written custom filters to do this, but there's nothing stock within the framework that does a more complex distortion than the existing uniform distortions. You might also be able to create a custom blend that uses a secondary image to perform a texture lookup displacement instead of a standard color-based blending.